# Use JS locally(without server-like environment) to save data

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I want to make a ToDo JavaScript **local** app for my self, how would I be able to store the data I add?

Of course I know how to make a script to create new elements etc, but how do I actually make it saved for the future access(without using cookies/local storage for verification)?

Comment: `(without using cookies/local storage for verification)` That's pretty much your only options

Comment: You must use local storage to save data.

Comment: Without using localStorage/Cookies/SessionStorage you have only one storage - YOUR MIND..

Comment: [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) is another option, assuming you're targeting modern browsers.

Comment: You can't do what you've literally asked, something has to give. Either use local storage or similar, or use something like Node to provide a server process on your machine your page talks to which stores the data for you. (It's about 10-15 lines of code using Express.)

Comment: @JoeClay that way WebSQL is also available.. if the OP wants to use it..

Comment: Yeah, but this doesn't really store data inside a file, am I right? I want to be able to save added elements to the same file

Comment: The IndexedDB version [is even already written for you](https://github.com/mdn/to-do-notifications/tree/gh-pages).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so basically I can't do that without server-side support? If I'll use cookies/local storage/IndexedDB, would I be able to save data permanently - without losing it after clearing the cache/cookies/local storage etc?

Comment: @laudbob: Right. Local storage is not a file. But you can add and remove elements from it. If you want a literal file, your **only** option is to run a process locally to do the file I/O. You can *read* a file from your computer in browser-hosted JavaScript (you'd have to manually select it, then read it via the File API), but not write one. Saving would be a matter of generating a big `data:` URI and triggering the browser's "Save as" dialog. Much simpler to just do a simple Node process.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder great app(at github - todo), but it doesn't save as I wish it will - after clearing the browser's cache etc it restores to it's previously, blank state. I can't use server languages for my case, gotta solve it somehow else. Thanks folks for clearing it out for me

Comment: @laudbob: *"I can't use server languages for my case"* The language used with Node is JavaScript, the same language you use in the browser, just a different environment.

Comment: @ShaktiPhartiyal: You *could* use WebSQL, but I wouldn't recommend it - it's been deprecated in favor of IndexedDB, so there's little to no chance it's ever going to be made widely available.